# Spin of an operator in supersymmetric theories

Tags: special-relativity, string-theory, quantum-spin, supersymmetry, group-representations

How exactly is the spin of an operator in the context of a supersymmetric theory defined? For example, in page 25 of [1], $\mathcal{N} = 2$ supersymmetry is defined to have operators $J, G^{+}, G^{-}, T$ with spin $1, \frac{3}{2}, \frac{3}{2}, 2$ respectively. What does this mean precisely? Given an operator in such a theory how can one deduce its "spin"?

---

[1] *Topological strings and their physical applications,* C. Vafa, A. Nietzke http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0410178.

Comment: Hint: check its conformal weight from its OPE with the energy-momentum tensor